# Flip view horizontally. Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, view

In my application there is only portrait mode. But I need to flip one view , but so that all other view are in portrait.
How i can  do it in XCode ?

Comment: The question is unclear.  What do you mean by 'flip one view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate any view using its transform property.

```
// landscapeLeft: angle = CGFloat.pi / 2
// landscapeRight: angle = -CGFloat.pi / 2

yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!